# jQuery picklist: shows only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

When using the jquery picklist (from: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/) I only get one list instead of 2 (left and right). Any ideas?

I almost copy pasted all from http://jsfiddle.net/awnry/ScX4S/

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TestSite</title>
    <link href="./css/test.css"  rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<script src="./scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery-picklist.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/test.js"></script>

    <div>
        <select name="basic" id="basic" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4" selected="selected">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
            <option value="6">Option 6</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#basic").picklist();
});
```

CSS Code:

```
 body { margin: 0.5em; }

.pickList_sourceListContainer, .pickList_controlsContainer, `.pickList_targetListContainer { float: left; margin: 0.25em; }`
.pickList_controlsContainer { text-align: center; }
.pickList_controlsContainer button { display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center; }
.pickList_list { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; width: 150px; height: 75px; border: 1px inset #eee; overflow-y: auto; cursor: default; }
.pickList_selectedListItem { background-color: #a3c8f5; }
.pickList_listLabel { font-size: 0.9em; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }
.pickList_clear { clear: both; }
```

Comment: It's working in your fiddle, or am i missing something?

Comment: It is working in fiddle, but not in my documents.

Comment: Did you check for console errors

Answer (score 1):

In your code, Change

```
<script src="./scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery-picklist.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="./scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery-picklist.js"></script>
```

**Reason :** You should include reference jquery UI widget before picklist. *(Check the ordering in the fiddle)*

The ordering matters as picklist refers the former(jquery UI widget library) for its functionality - **[Reference](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/wiki/Demos)**.

Comment: @Anton, sorry, forgot to format the first reference(4 spaces). Thanks for the find!

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, it was indeed a mistake but it didn't solve the problem.